# Can't install Jenkins public key on Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a Ubuntu EC2 Instance on AWS.

I am following this steps:https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/

after I ssh into my Instance, I type

`wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Then time is frozen, nothing happens on my cmd, no response.

Any suggestions how to install the jenkins.io.key? any tricks?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct order should be as follows:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -

echo 'deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After that install Java. Then execute the following command:

```
apt-get update

apt-get install jenkins
```

Can you please try this solution.